# Can't get summary or weights from loaded keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I saved a keras model using model.save(model_path). Now when I try to load it and apply model.summary() or model.get_weights() function I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Tried printing the data type of the model and got following whereas it was a sequential keras model when I had saved it:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject'>
```

I am using tensorflow 2.4.1(cpu). Below sample code can help recreating the error:

```
def save_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model_path = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
    hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_path, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=False)
    model.add(hub_layer)
    model.save('/home/pcadmin/data/models/sentence_embedding/use-4-pre-trained/')

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
print(model.summary())
model.get_weights()
```

Comment: Would you mind to response the given answer and giving some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

The reproducible code above isn't complete I think. However, you need to change the code as follows to make it run. (I've tested on cpu/gpu with `tf 2.4/2.7`.)

```
model_path = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"

def save_model(model_path):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_path, 
                               input_shape=[], 
                               dtype=tf.string, trainable=False)
    model.add(hub_layer)
    model.save('saved/')

save_model(model_path)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/saved')
model.summary() # OK 
model.get_weights() # OK
```